# How to make Express return a new html with axios post

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, authentication, axios

I have an express server. I have two routes as get methods.

```
app.get('/main',(req, res) => {
     res.sendFile(`main.html`, {root: staticPath});
});
app.get('/signin', (req, res) => {
     res.sendFile('signin.html', {root: staticPath});
});
```

I want to build my app as a single page react application. But before I let the user see this single page, I want to show a sign in, sign up screen. So when user clicks the sign in or sign up buttons, I want to send signin.html as response from the express server.

Here is my code on the browser from a react class

```
SignIn(){
    axios.get('signin');
}
```

I can console.log() from the express route and verify that the code gets executed within the 'signin' route, but the html view doesn't change on the browser even though I send back a html file. How do I make it happen?

Answer (score 2):

I'm by no means an expert, but here are my two cents. Instead of setting up your front end to receive an HTML file from the server, a more efficient approach would be the following.

- Build the signup and login pages on the front end.
- Set up routing between these pages.
- Send the login/signup details from client to server via `/login` or `/signup` routes that you set up in Express. These details would usually be in the `req.body` object (make sure to install the [bodyparser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser) package from NPM).
- You could then use JWTs to authenticate users and maintain sessions.

If you're looking for server-side rendering with React, here is an [article](https://medium.com/front-end-hacking/server-side-rendering-with-react-and-express-382591bfc77c) for your reading pleasure :) Sorry if I made no sense.